# Cannot update metadata - Kafka Producer for Cloudera Quickstart VM

Tags: apache-kafka

I just installed Cloudera QuickStart VM and added Kafka service to it. After adding the Kafka service, I could easily create a producer/consumer and everything worked as expected. After a couple of days and the restart of the VM, I am getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$FutureFailure.(KafkaProducer.java:1124)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:823)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:760)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:648)
>       at test.kafka.KafkaProducerExample.runProducer(KafkaProducerExample.java:37)
>       at test.kafka.KafkaProducerExample.main(KafkaProducerExample.java:54)
>   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.

I tried to connect with telnet to port 9092 and it works. I am able to send messages from inside the QuickStart VM. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting the zookeeper logs as well as your kafka brokers log and then try to run your I think it will work. It’s not working because it’s getting the old logs. You can change the log dir path from zookeeper.properties, and server.properties.

Answer (score -1):

```
val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String](settings.topic, notification.tableName, notification.toJson())
    producer.send(record).**get**
/**
     * Waits if necessary for at most the given time for the computation
     * to complete, and then retrieves its result, if available.
     *
     * @param timeout the maximum time to wait
     * @param unit the time unit of the timeout argument
     * @return the computed result
     * @throws CancellationException if the computation was cancelled
     * @throws ExecutionException if the computation threw an
     * exception
     * @throws InterruptedException if the current thread was interrupted
     * while waiting
     * @throws TimeoutException if the wait timed out
     */
```